# Usage of ngStorage(angularjs) for language option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-storage

I have this HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="setLanguage('en')">English</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="setLanguage('de')">Danish</button>
<p>{{name[language]}}</p>
```

and javascript

```
$scope.language='en';  //initial default value
$scope.setLanguage = function(language) {
    $scope.language = language;    
   }
```

i am binding language to button for 2 languages.based on the language selected, the content will be shown. how to store `en` or `de` to localstorage. if i refresh or change the page also, the set language should be same. how to do it. can anyone help me
Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/zHMvBWCKevKgGeBerhhE?p=preview

Comment: are you looking for `localStorage.setItem(key, value)` and `localStorage.getItem(key)`? I don't know why you need ngStorage if you just want to use localStorage.

Comment: No, but the same thing. i have used ngStorage. https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage , but i don't know , how to use it. If you can tell me in your own way. which you told above, that is also ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Getter
if ($window.localStorage.language) {
    $scope.language = $window.localStorage.language;
} else {
    $scope.language = 'en';
}


// Setter
$scope.setLanguage = function(language) {
    $scope.language = language;
    $window.localStorage.language = language;
}
```

To check your resource variables like cookies, local storage, etc. Under chrome developer tools (access with F12) go to `Resources` tab.

Comment: Does it needs ngStorage or without that

Comment: Nope. It works just fine without it :) You just need to inject `$window`. But you can also use `window` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it didn't work. i have checked local storage in resources, it is en after refreshing the page. it was not changed

Comment: I have used same thing as above in my project as in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/nrRNWggwZVpgEk7wwzzi?p=preview.
but in plunker it is working,but not in my project. can you tell me why

Comment: If it is a different controller, is that leads to problem? I mean button is in different controller and  view, and content in different view and controller

Comment: It doesn't matter. Controllers use the same local storage.

Comment: Oh actually it does when you try to use the same scope variable in the both controller. They don't share the same scope. So `$scope.language` will be different for both. And won't update upon clicking the button if the display is in another controller and view. To share data between controllers you need to use either `services` or `$rootScope` events.

Comment: Check this answer for sharing data between controllers with services - [Share data between AngularJS controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: If you don't mind, can you show me in code. how to share for my code. because i am not getting how to do it

Comment: Check the article I just provided you in my previous comment. It is already answered :) Hope that helps you

Comment: i saw it, but i am not getting how to use it with local storage, where to use local storage

Comment: The same way. The only difference is that you set and get your language to and from your factory instead of your `$scope` variable `language`. You should really read some documentation first to understand the basic concepts.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-storage` is amazingly simple.

Inject `ngStorage` in to your main module and `$localStorage` to your controller.

```
$scope.setLanguage = function(language) {
    $scope.language = language;    

    $localStorage.language = language;

   }
```

---

If you need to persist data across refreshes, think of using [ng-cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies).

Inject `ngCookies` into your main module. Also insert `$cookies` into your controller.

Then you can use `$cookies.put` and `$cookies.get` for storing and retrieving data.

```
$scope.setLanguage = function(language) {
    $scope.language = language;    

    $cookies.put('language', language);

   }
```

Also note that you should use the [cookie expiry date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider#defaults) to set the TTL.

Comment: I have tried it already, but it is not working, if i refresh, it will again move to en. is there any way to check in chrome, whether it is stored in localstorage

Comment: Probably you should use $cookies

Comment: Its part of angular js. Comes as an additional module. (<script src="angular-cookies.js">)

Comment: Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/zHMvBWCKevKgGeBerhhE?p=preview
if i include $cookies in controller, i will get some error. see the plunker above

Comment: Your problem is the disparity of versions of angular and ng-cookies. If you use angular 1.2.x then you should use an-cookies 1.2.x too.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you show it, how to add http://plnkr.co/edit/uOuTQEquJ0rrNJQagRba?p=preview
$cookies.get('language', language);

Comment: When you say  `console.log($cookies.get('language'));` what you see is what function returns. Nothing else.

Comment: Anyway, `$cookies.ge`t and `$cookies.put` are very simple methods and works just fine in your plunker. I don't think there is anyway I can help you beyond this point.

Comment: So, this is not any more a problem of local storage and cookies. This is a problem of ,sharing data between controllers.

Comment: even in plunker, the cookie data gonna lost, if  i click refresh http://plnkr.co/edit/bLsFhA8BF5Hg9whCBnAU?p=preview

Comment: That is because of the handling of cookies by plunker. ng-cookies is a well tested module and is working without a problem.

Comment: See this plunker, i have used local storage. it works well if i click refresh also http://plnkr.co/edit/nrRNWggwZVpgEk7wwzzi?p=preview

Comment: Thats why I said your problem is not with localstorage or cookies. It is about sharing data.

Answer (score 1):

You ca use:

```
window.localStorage['storageVariableName'] = language;
```

and if you want to save as jason format use

```
window.localStorage['storageVariableName'] = angular.tojson(language);
```

and access data

```
$scope.language = window.localStorage['storageVariableName'];
```